# Different behaviour of Cassandra java driver on android and other os

Tags: java, android, cassandra

I have the problem in android, that I got a JKS not found (driver exception) for the same file, where a local UnitTest doesn't complain.

Version: **com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core:4.17.0** (older not working too)

I think the problem could relate to the different location of JavaKeystore on both OS.

com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverExecutionException
cause = java.security.KeyStoreException: JKS not found

com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.concurrent.CompletableFutures.getUninterruptibly(CompletableFutures.java:152)
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.SessionBuilder.build(SessionBuilder.java:835)
...getSession(Datastax.java:105)

The following code only works on local machine not on android:

```
// Create the CqlSession object:
    try {
        CqlSession session = CqlSession.builder().withCloudSecureConnectBundle(bis)
                .withAuthCredentials(
                  CryptoChain.byteArrayToString(CryptoChain.encryptBlockwise(Datastax.class.getName().getBytes(), ush))
                 ,CryptoChain.byteArrayToString(CryptoChain.encryptBlockwise(Datastax.class.getName().getBytes(), pwh)))
                .build();
        return session;
    }catch (final Exception e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

The full stacktrace:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.abc.testapp, PID: 13518
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.abc.testapp/com.abc.testapp.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.RuntimeException:
> com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverExecutionException
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3455)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3598)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2164)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7582)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverExecutionException
> at com.abc.testapp.dataapi.Datastax.getSession(Datastax.java:116)
> at com.abc.testapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:636)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7822)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7811)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1328)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3430)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3598) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2164) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7582) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941) 
> Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverExecutionException
> at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.concurrent.CompletableFutures.getUninterruptibly(CompletableFutures.java:152)
> at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.SessionBuilder.build(SessionBuilder.java:835)
> at com.abc.testapp.dataapi.Datastax.getSession(Datastax.java:111)
> at com.abc.testapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:636) 
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7822) 
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7811) 
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1328) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3430) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3598) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2164) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7582) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941) 
> Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: JKS not found
> at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:890)
> at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.config.cloud.CloudConfigFactory.createKeyManagerFactory(CloudConfigFactory.java:202)
> at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.config.cloud.CloudConfigFactory.createSslContext(CloudConfigFactory.java:191)
> at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.config.cloud.CloudConfigFactory.createCloudConfig(CloudConfigFactory.java:129)
> at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.SessionBuilder.buildDefaultSessionAsync(SessionBuilder.java:876)
> at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.SessionBuilder.buildAsync(SessionBuilder.java:817)
> at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.SessionBuilder.build(SessionBuilder.java:835) 
> at com.abc.testapp.dataapi.Datastax.getSession(Datastax.java:111) 
> at com.abc.testapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:636) 
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7822) 
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7811) 
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1328) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3430) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3598) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2164) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7582) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941) 
> Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: JKS KeyStore not available
> at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
> at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:628)
> at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:887)
> at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.config.cloud.CloudConfigFactory.createKeyManagerFactory(CloudConfigFactory.java:202) 
> at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.config.cloud.CloudConfigFactory.createSslContext(CloudConfigFactory.java:191) 
> at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.config.cloud.CloudConfigFactory.createCloudConfig(CloudConfigFactory.java:129) 
> at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.SessionBuilder.buildDefaultSessionAsync(SessionBuilder.java:876) 
> at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.SessionBuilder.buildAsync(SessionBuilder.java:817) 
> at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.SessionBuilder.build(SessionBuilder.java:835) 
> at com.abc.testapp.dataapi.Datastax.getSession(Datastax.java:111) 
> at com.abc.testapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:636) 
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7822) 
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7811) 
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1328) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3430) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3598) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2164) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7582) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)

Comment: To help understand the issue better, please post (1) the full error message + (2) the full stack trace. Cheers!

Comment: Did you try printing the full path, stacktrace, etc?

Comment: I edited my question and added the full stacktrace.